# Should I be using node-uuid or uuid?

Tags: node.js, uuid

On npmjs.com there are packages for both `node-uuid` and `uuid`. Which should I be using? They're the same API, one is forked from the other, and divergent in commits.

Comment: Consider the real problem, you need to generate uuid, you have the choice between two very popular tools (so they should both work great) doing exactly the same thing the same way, the choice can be made by flipping a coin.

Comment: Maybe the [node-uuid](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid) could be better, as there are more starts here, also issue could be discussed quickly here.. Generally speaking, this is opinion based, I'd like to choose the package with more stars and more discussion here..

Comment: I keep flip-flopping between the two, which I suppose means I'm flipping a coin every time I install one or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uuid` is the actively maintained project / package. The projects have been merged.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `uuid` module is a fork of `node-uuid` from when the `node-uuid` author wasn't being very responsive. See: https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid/issues/116

Looking at the recent commit history of the two projects, it looks like a community member has stepped up and has been maintaining `node-uuid`, while `uuid` doesn't seem to be actively maintained, so I decided to pick `node-uuid`.